# How to show a route change transition with a progress bar like NProgress in Next JS 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

in Next JS < 13 we had `router.events` and in the `_app.js` we could add an effect like

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import NProgress from 'nprogress'

const Main = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    const router = useRouter()

    useEffect(function nprogressOnRouteChange() {
        router.events.on('routeChangeStart', NProgress.start)
        router.events.on('routeChangeError', NProgress.done)
        router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', NProgress.done)

        return () => {
            router.events.off('routeChangeStart', NProgress.start)
            router.events.off('routeChangeError', NProgress.done)
            router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', NProgress.done)

            NProgress.remove()
        }
    }, [])

    ...
}
```

but now the `useRouter` has been moved to `next/navigation`, and the hook returned object
no longer has any event property in it, **am I missing anything**?

tried importing the `Router` from `next/router` in the new `layout.tsx` file but the events are not working there either

```
import Router from 'next/router'
export default function Transition({ children }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => {
            console.log('start')
        })
    }, [])

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//this worked for me, hope it helps!
//so you turn it on when you leave the page, and off when you land on another page

import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import NProgress from 'nprogress'
import 'nprogress/nprogress.css'

export default async function Home() {
const pathname = usePathname()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()

  useEffect(() => {
    NProgress.done();
    return () => {
      NProgress.start();
    };
  }, [pathname, searchParams]);

  return (
    <>
     ...
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: by the way there is a progress bar in the experimiental features (next.config.js) but it didt work for me so implemented the nprogress one

Comment: this effect needs to be on every single page ! 

Comment: so i think it was showing twice, i removed the progress.start and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @fedscorner for the answer, and I made some changes, now it works!

You can use the `Progress` component in `app/layout.js`.

*The `primary` is a color, you can assign it to any value or just remove it.*

```js
'use client'

import 'nprogress/nprogress.css'
import NProgress from 'nprogress'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import { primary } from '@/theme/palette'

NProgress.configure({
  template: `<div class="bar" role="bar" style="height:3px;background:${primary.main}"></div>`,
})

export default function Progress() {
  const pathname = usePathname()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()

  useEffect(() => {
    NProgress.done()
    return () => {
      NProgress.start()
    }
  }, [pathname, searchParams])

  return <></>
}
```